# GUI Wallet not syncing and Coins not appearing in wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization, error-log, daemon

I have downloaded Monero gui 0.10.3.1-beta 2 wallet.

I sent coins to my wallet from an exchange prior to the wallet finishing syncing.

My coins are not visible in my wallet. It has been 4 days and the wallet has not finished syncing. At one point the remaining blocks started increasing and I had to close the program and leave the daemon running in the background to fix this.

I have been receiving these errors:

```
2017-07-03 07:59:28.984 9040    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
2017-07-03 07:59:30.276 9040    ERROR   msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:94   Error: Couldn't connect to daemon
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon
```

I'm not very proficient with computers but can follow instructions if clear and detailed.

I don't have the best computer, but am running Windows 10 64bit.

Can someone please let me know how to fix this and if my coins are safe?

Comment: That "Couldn't connect to daemon" message means that the daemon isn't running where the GUI expects it. By default, the GUI expects it to run on the local host, on the default port. Did you ever change this in the settings page ? If so, reset it. If you did not, did you choose to run the daemon when the GUI asked ? If not, are you running a daemon manually ?

Comment: Thank you for your response, to speed up the process I changed from a host node to a local node.

Comment: If you change to a local node, you have to make sure it's started. monero-wallet-gui will ask on startup whether you want to do so. There's also a button to start it in the settings IIRC.